# Serving blob from app-engine endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin, gae-eclipse-plugin

I want to serve a blob from my google endpoint server to an android app; not a link to the blob, the actual blob. Do I have to encode the blob in Base64 to send it from the endpoint or is that handled by app-engine?

Please do not confuse this question with the reverse path of sending image from front-end to backend. I want to send from the SERVER to the CLIENT. Do I need to encode the blob or does app-engine handle that? Oh, and I am using Java.

Comment: I suggest you to send the url which can be obtained by ImageService Apis of GAE by passing a blobkey, and that url can be used anywhere on the web as a normal source attribute for img tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to encode the blob in Base64. You can have a field in an Object that you're returning that contains an array of bytes. Marshalling will be handled by the Cloud Endpoints layer for you.