# What parameter types are supported by Google Endpoints in an API method?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I can make String, Date and Long work. If I use byte[] I get an error when I run the endpoints.sh script. I can find nothing in the documentation that lists the types supported and the errors generated a pretty cryptic. I'd like to get a little bit of binary (image) data into an endpoint method. This is no good:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "device.bikeImage.set")
public void setDeviceBikeImage(com.google.appengine.api.users.User appEngineUser,
        @Named("facebookAccessToken") @Nullable String facebookAccessToken,
        @Named("deviceId") String deviceId, @Named("bikeImage") byte[] bikeImage)
        throws IOException, OAuthRequestException {
}
```

What types are supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatypes supported are described in the docs for endpoints, [right here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types).

> The supported parameter types are the following:
>
> java.lang.String java.lang.Boolean and boolean 
>   java.lang.Integer and int 
>   java.lang.Long and long java.lang.Float and float 
> java.lang.Double
>   and double
>  java.util.Date
>  com.google.api.server.spi.types.DateAndTime
>   com.google.api.server.spi.types.SimpleDate
>  Any enum
>  Any array or
>   java.util.Collection of a parameter type

Comment: Thanks. This is new documentation that didn't exist at the time the question was posted, but I'll accept it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The following article has a list of the value types that are supported (go to the "Properties and Value Types" section:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities

When working with Endpoints, you are definitely limited to only those types that can be serialized into JSON.

There is also minimal discussion on serving blobs from Endpoints in these two questions:

1. [How can I upload an thumbnail image (blob) at the same time as an Entity into a datastore in google app engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306790/how-can-i-upload-an-thumbnail-image-blob-at-the-same-time-as-an-entity-into-a/15309278#15309278)
2. [Serving blob from app-engine endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951709/serving-blob-from-app-engine-endpoint)